# Replace multiplce characters in a file

Tags: java, replace, char, character

I want to replace turkisch characters `{ 'ç', 'Ç', 'İ', 'ı', 'Ğ', 'ğ', 'Ş', 'ş' }`  with new english characters `{ 'c', 'C', 'I', 'i', 'G', 'g', 'S', 's' }`  in a textfile.

Here is my code. I get only the original content without changes on the Console and it does not creat a new file.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Replace {

    String line = null;
    String ret = null;

    public void doIt() {
        try {

            File f1 = new File("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\new-words2.txt");
            FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(f1);
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
            FileReader("C:\\\\Users\\\\PC\\\\Desktop\\new-words.txt"));

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f1);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                char[] turkishChars = new char[] { 'ç', 'Ç', 'İ', 'ı', 'Ğ', 'ğ', 'Ş', 'ş' };
                char[] englishChars = new char[] { 'c', 'C', 'I', 'i', 'G', 'g', 'S', 's' };
                for (int i = 0; i < turkishChars.length; i++) {
                    ret = ret.replaceAll(new String(new char[] { turkishChars[i] }),
                            new String(new char[] { englishChars[i] }));
                    out.write(ret);
                }
            }

            fr.close();
            br.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Main1 fr = new Main1();
        fr.doIt();

    }
}
```

Edit:

This is the new code that works for me. But I would like to use a shorter code for the replace method.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Replace {

    String line = null;
    String ret = null;

    public void doIt() {
        try {

            File f1 = new File("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\new-words2.txt");
            FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(f1);
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
            FileReader("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\new-words.txt"));

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f1);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                ret = line.replace("ç", "c").replace("Ç", "C").replace("İ", "I").replace("ı", "i").replace("Ğ", "G")
                        .replace("ğ", "g").replace("Ş", "S").replace("ş", "s");
                out.write(ret + "\n");
            }

            fr.close();
            br.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Replace fr = new Replace();
        fr.doIt();

    }
}
```

Comment: You are not using the `line` that you read. And you probably just get a stack print and ignore it.

Comment: Also, in the `main` method an instance of type `Main1` is instatiated, but the code shown here is the type `Replace`. So, actually, this may even not be the code that is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I have little knowledge about this topic, but can it be that your program doesn't detect the br FileReader path due to 4 backslashes? Change them to two (FileReader("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\new-words.txt"))
and try again. Maybe that helps something.